# How to escape quotes in dotnet test --filter

Tags: shell, unit-testing, .net-core, command-line-interface

I'd like to run tests from commandline using `dotnet test --filter`,
I have tests with fully qualified name similar to:

```
Namespace.MyTest(Param,"TEST_1").TestMethod
```

Is there any way to escape quotes in the filter argument?

```
dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName=Namespace.MyTest(Param%2c\"TEST_1\").TestMethod"
```

I've found nothing in docs and tried almost anything

```
\", "", ^", """
```

Or any other tips how to run this?

Thanks..

Comment: Which docs did you check? These strings are handled by your operating system and shell, not `dotnet`. You need to use the escaping rules of your shell (bash, zsh, PowerShell, cmd)

Comment: `Param%2c\"` ? Percent-encoding is used in URLs, not CLI shells. You *don't* need to escape commas at all though. Perhaps *that's* what caused the problem?

Comment: Looking at the docs, you should also be using `<...>` instead of `(...)`. For example `dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName=MyNamespace.MyTestsClass<ParameterType1%2CParameterType2>.MyTestMethod"`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't think you're right, see https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=nunit

Comment: @DavidG that's for generic class, this FullyQualifiedName really has ``(...)`` in it, because is defined by TestFixture attribute on the class:``[TestFixture(ParamVal1,"TEST_1")]``